# Декларация аргумента функции - передача имени класса

Tags: php

есть произвольный класс например `class Shop implements \IShop {}` и есть другой класс например

```
class Product
{
 private $shop;

 public function __construct(\IShop $shop)
 {
  $this->shop = $shop;
 }
}

$product = new Product(Shop::class);
```

выдаст ошибку, потому как `Shop::class` передается в виде строки, а экземпляр не нужен - так как все методы будут статичными, пробовал указывать тип в аргументе не класс, а интерфейс - результат тот же.

Вопрос: как сделать проверку  - что это именно тот класс или интерфейс который мне  нужен, можно даже на основе интерфейса

Comment: я предполагал что есть функции на подобии - получить класс по имени и функция - содержит ли класс интерфейс

Comment: Ну и если экземпляр не нужен, то зачем писать `\IShop` в определении аргумента?

Comment: У вас класс Product ожидает на входе не строку, а экземпляр класса IShop или его наследника. $product = new Product(new Shop());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выяснить, является ли класс наследником другого класса (или интерфейса) зная только названия этих классов (строки) можно с помощью [`is_subclass_of`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-subclass-of.php#refsect1-function.is-subclass-of-examples).